# Loop Updating Chart Image on Userform

Tags: excel, loops, charts, userform, vba

Okay,

So I am trying to integrate the following code:

```
`Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim Fname As String

    Call SaveChart
    Fname = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\temp1.gif"
    Me.Image1.Picture = LoadPicture(Fname)
End Sub

Private Sub SaveChart()
    Dim MyChart As Chart
    Dim Fname As String

    Set MyChart = Sheets("Data").ChartObjects(1).Chart
    Fname = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\temp1.gif"
    MyChart.Export Filename:=Fname, FilterName:="GIF"
End Sub`
```

from this post: [Displaying "live" chart data in Excel Userform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31598704/displaying-live-chart-data-in-excel-userform/31600919#3160091) into an existing loop so that the above section of code iterates with the loop and the image is updated every time the loop executes.  I would have posted this as a comment on the above mentioned question, but I do not have enough rep.

```
'
' Get last logged data
'
Private Sub GetLastLoggedData()
    Dim rangeToWrite
    Dim lStartFileSize As Long
    Dim lNextFileSize As Long
    Dim dtStartTime As Date
    Dim lElapsedTime As Long
    Dim bDone As Boolean
    Dim sLastHeader As String
    Dim sLastData As String
    Dim iCol As Integer
    Dim sNextValue As String
    Dim iLoop As Integer
    Dim Fname As String
    Dim MyChart As Chart

    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

   ' Initialize global_bHasScanCount flag
   global_bHasScanCount = False

   ' Get the file size of the log file
    lStartFileSize = FileLen(global_sLogFile)

    ' Initialize timer
    dtStartTime = Now

    ' Wait for filesize to change
    UpdateLogStatus Now & " : Data Monitor: waiting for file size to change..."
    bDone = False
    Do
        ' Get the file size of the log file and see if it's changed
        lNextFileSize = FileLen(global_sLogFile)
        If lNextFileSize <> lStartFileSize And lNextFileSize <> 0 Then
            bDone = True
        Else
            lElapsedTime = DateDiff("s", dtStartTime, Now)
            If (lElapsedTime >= global_lTimeout) Or (lElapsedTime < 0) Then
                bDone = True
            End If
        End If

        DoEvents

    Loop Until bDone = True

    ' Backup the file
    UpdateLogStatus Now & " : Data Monitor: backing up data file..."
    'FileCopy global_sLogFile, global_sLogFileBackup

    ' Read the log file
    UpdateLogStatus Now & " : Data Monitor: reading data file..."
    sLastData = ""
    sLastHeader = ""

    If ReadLogFile(global_sLogFile, sLastData, sLastHeader) = False Then
        ' Delete the backup log file
        'Kill global_sLogFileBackup

        Exit Sub
    End If

    ' Delete the backup log file
    'Kill global_sLogFileBackup

    UpdateLogStatus Now & " : Data Monitor: updating worksheet..."


    ' Clear previous Results in Excel Spreadsheet
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("ACQUIRE DATA").Range("A2:IV2").ClearContents

    ' Parse comma delimeted header and place data into worksheet cells.  If we have the scan count then
    ' start writing in column1, else starting writing in column2.

    If global_bHasScanCount = True Then
        iCol = 1
    Else
        iCol = 2
    End If

    If sLastHeader <> "" Then
        ' Clear previous Results in Excel Spreadsheet
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("ACQUIRE DATA").Range("A1:IV1").ClearContents

        Do
            sNextValue = GetToken(sLastHeader, ",")

            ' Copy Results to Excel worksheet
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("ACQUIRE DATA").Cells(1, iCol).Value = sNextValue
            iCol = iCol + 1

        Loop Until sLastHeader = ""
    End If

    ' Parse comma delimeted results and place data into worksheet cells.  If we have the scan count then
    ' start writing in column1, else starting writing in column2.

    If global_bHasScanCount = True Then
        iCol = 1
    Else
        iCol = 2
    End If
    Do
        sNextValue = GetToken(sLastData, ",")

        ' Copy Results to Excel worksheet
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("ACQUIRE DATA").Cells(2, iCol).Value = sNextValue
        iCol = iCol + 1
        'Copy Current Data to Control Panel
        UserForm2.TextBox2.Text = Sheets("ACQUIRE DATA").Range("B12")
        'Copy Time to Control Panel 
        UserForm2.TextBox3 = Format(Sheets("ACQUIRE DATA").Range("B13"), "hh:mm:ss")
        'Copy Speed to Control Panel 
        UserForm2.TextBox4.Text = Sheets("ACQUIRE DATA").Range("B14")

   'create .gif file of current PerfMap chart
    Set MyChart = Sheets("PerfMap").ChartObjects(1).Chart
    Fname = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\temp1.gif"
    MyChart.Export Filename:=Fname, FilterName:="GIF"
    Fname = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\temp1.gif"
    'set live data chart image to most recent image
    UserForm3.Image1.Picture = LoadPicture(Fname)


    Loop Until sLastData = ""
    UpdateLogStatus ""



    Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
    BuildErrorMessage "GetLastLoggedData", "Failed to get last logged data."
    UpdateLogStatus ""



End Sub'
```

However whenever I do this I get a Runtime Error 1004 that is built by the error handler.  Any help on why this is not working is much appreciated.

**EDIT**: After walking away for 24 hours, I realized that the sheet in question is a chart sheet, and not an embedded chart, therefore the method I was attempting to use above was not working.

The chart is on a chart sheet called PerfMap, but the chart name is Chart 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code solved my problem.

```
'create .gif file of current PerfMap chart
    Set PerfMap = Charts("PerfMap")
    Fname = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\temp1.bmp"
    PerfMap.Export Filename:=Fname, FilterName:="BMP"

    'set live data chart image to most recent image
    UserForm3.Image1.Picture = LoadPicture(Fname)
```

According to this MSDN https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/175918 one must use BMP to get the picture to work properly.

Now my new problem is that the above code slows my loop to a crawl and over time I end up using 99% of my system memory until I exit excel and re-open it.