# Excel VBA Loop Consumes All Memory

Tags: vba, excel, loops, memory-leaks

**Full Code at Bottom**
So after answering my own question regarding creating a real time chart image on a userform, see here: [Loop Updating Chart Image on Userform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37554571/loop-updating-chart-image-on-userform), I am now forced to ask another question, why do the top 3 lines of code cause me to consume all of my available ram in the course of ~ 7 minutes with this loop iterating approximately 12 times per minute?

```
Set PerfMap = Charts("PerfMap")
    Fname = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\temp1.bmp"
    PerfMap.Export Filename:=Fname, FilterName:="BMP"

    'set live data chart image to most recent image
    UserForm3.Image1.Picture = LoadPicture(Fname)

    'attempt to stop massive memleak in  above code
    Set PerfMap = Nothing
    Kill Fname
```

When these lines of code are commented out, the loop operates quickly and efficiently and memory usage is constant no matter how long the loop is left running.  This has been done for 3 days or more by accident.  As you can see below the three offending lines of code, I tried to fix it by unloading the variables that are responsible (PerfMap and Fname), but to no avail.

Thanks in advance for any help you may be able to offer.

**Edit 1:** added full code.  Memory only freed when Excel is closed.

```
Private Sub GetLastLoggedData()
    Dim rangeToWrite
    Dim lStartFileSize As Long
    Dim lNextFileSize As Long
    Dim dtStartTime As Date
    Dim lElapsedTime As Long
    Dim bDone As Boolean
    Dim sLastHeader As String
    Dim sLastData As String
    Dim iCol As Integer
    Dim sNextValue As String
    Dim iLoop As Integer
    Dim Fname As String
    Dim PerfMap As Chart

    Fname = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\temp1.bmp"


    'On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

   ' Initialize global_bHasScanCount flag
   global_bHasScanCount = False

   ' Get the file size of the log file
    lStartFileSize = FileLen(global_sLogFile)

    ' Initialize timer
    dtStartTime = Now

    ' Wait for filesize to change
    UpdateLogStatus Now & " : Data Monitor: waiting for file size to change..."
    bDone = False
    Do
        ' Get the file size of the log file and see if it's changed
        lNextFileSize = FileLen(global_sLogFile)
        If lNextFileSize <> lStartFileSize And lNextFileSize <> 0 Then
            bDone = True
        Else
            lElapsedTime = DateDiff("s", dtStartTime, Now)
            If (lElapsedTime >= global_lTimeout) Or (lElapsedTime < 0) Then
                bDone = True
            End If
        End If

        DoEvents

    Loop Until bDone = True

    ' Backup the file
    UpdateLogStatus Now & " : Data Monitor: backing up data file..."
    'FileCopy global_sLogFile, global_sLogFileBackup

    ' Read the log file
    UpdateLogStatus Now & " : Data Monitor: reading data file..."
    sLastData = ""
    sLastHeader = ""

    If ReadLogFile(global_sLogFile, sLastData, sLastHeader) = False Then
        ' Delete the backup log file
        'Kill global_sLogFileBackup

        Exit Sub
    End If

    ' Delete the backup log file
    'Kill global_sLogFileBackup

    UpdateLogStatus Now & " : Data Monitor: updating worksheet..."


    ' Clear previous Results in Excel Spreadsheet
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("ACQUIRE DATA").Range("A2:IV2").ClearContents

    ' Parse comma delimeted header and place data into worksheet cells.  If we have the scan count then
    ' start writing in column1, else starting writing in column2.

    If global_bHasScanCount = True Then
        iCol = 1
    Else
        iCol = 2
    End If

    If sLastHeader <> "" Then
        ' Clear previous Results in Excel Spreadsheet
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("ACQUIRE DATA").Range("A1:IV1").ClearContents

        Do
            sNextValue = GetToken(sLastHeader, ",")

            ' Copy Results to Excel worksheet
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("ACQUIRE DATA").Cells(1, iCol).Value = sNextValue
            iCol = iCol + 1

        Loop Until sLastHeader = ""
    End If

    ' Parse comma delimeted results and place data into worksheet cells.  If we have the scan count then
    ' start writing in column1, else starting writing in column2.

    If global_bHasScanCount = True Then
        iCol = 1
    Else
        iCol = 2
    End If
    Do
        sNextValue = GetToken(sLastData, ",")

        ' Copy Results to Excel worksheet
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("ACQUIRE DATA").Cells(2, iCol).Value = sNextValue
        iCol = iCol + 1
        'Copy Current Data to Control Panel
        UserForm2.TextBox2.Text = Sheets("ACQUIRE DATA").Range("B12")
        'Copy Time to Control Panel (added 2/9/16 by KAK)
        UserForm2.TextBox3 = Format(Sheets("ACQUIRE DATA").Range("B13"), "hh:mm:ss")
        'Copy Speed to Control Panel (added 2/9/16 by KAK)
        UserForm2.TextBox4.Text = Sheets("ACQUIRE DATA").Range("B14")

   'create .bmp file of current PerfMap chart
    Set PerfMap = Charts("PerfMap")
    'Fname = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\temp1.bmp"
    PerfMap.Export Filename:=Fname, FilterName:="BMP"

    'set live data chart image to most recent image
    UserForm3.Image1.Picture = LoadPicture(Fname)

    'attempt to stop massive memleak with above code
    Set PerfMap = Nothing
    'Kill Fname


    Loop Until sLastData = ""
    UpdateLogStatus ""

'Added by Travis
'    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Comp GAS PROP").Range("B56:B63").Copy
'    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Comp Pt 10").Range("D51").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
'    Application.CutCopyMode = False
'
'    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("ACQUIRE DATA").Range("B56:B65").Copy
'    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Real Time").Range("D51").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
'    Application.CutCopyMode = False
'    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("ACQUIRE DATA").Range("B11:B51").Copy
'    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Real Time").Range("K5:K45").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
'    Application.CutCopyMode = False
'End of Added

    Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
    BuildErrorMessage "GetLastLoggedData", "Failed to get last logged data."
    UpdateLogStatus ""



End Sub
```

Comment: Are you clearing all objects, or other variables that may take up a lot of memory? Can you post the full working code?

Comment: I can but it is long, will edit original post.

Comment: exporting a chart image is resource intensive as it is...

Comment: It is the only workable method I have found for creating a 'live' chart on a userform in the vba environment.  I think that I am reaching the limits of what Excel can be used to do as a replacement for a dedicated program.

Comment: If you have working code which merely needs improvements then you're probably in the wrong place with this post. [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) is where they handle existing / working code and do their upmost to improve it in terms of speed, security, sustainability, and longevity. Give it a try. They're good!

Comment: My apologies, I did not know such a place existed.

Comment: you can avoid export/loadpicture , by doing this : `Pic.copy : userform.image1.picture=Pastepicture`. the code of pastepicture cn be found in a google search (just a module to add to your project). it uses the clipboard as intermediary instead of the disk.

Comment: Thank you Patrick, I will give this method a try and see if this solves my titanic-sized memory leak, however I am afraid that without a method to clear the clipboard my memory problems will continue unabated.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge BMP is a huge format to work with in any platform, why don't you try PNG instead? If you are concerned about pic quality, try the following:

```
'This sorts out the quality by making the pasted image larger before exporting.  Change the value from 3 to whatever you like. 1 will not improve quality, 10 will make the output filesize huge.
With ActiveSheet
.Shapes("PerfMap").ScaleWidth 3, msoFalse, msoScaleFromTopLeft
.Shapes("PerfMap").ScaleHeight 3, msoFalse, msoScaleFromTopLeft
End With

'You can export to any image format here.  Ensure the file extension matches the filtername.
ActiveChart.Export Filename:=fName, filtername:="PNG"
```

Comment: I tried to use a PNG filter initially but got a runtime error 481, and then discovered this MSDN article https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/175918.  I would prefer not to use BMP since the filesize is so large, but according to the MSDN article it can't be done.

Comment: Did you try the implement the posted code? It works for me and has a nice quality

Comment: I was working on integrating it now, unfortunately the chart is not the active sheet and is a chart sheet and not just an embedded chart so I am having to dance around that a bit.

Comment: According to what I read in your code, you would need to change it for With Sheets("ACQUIRE DATA") and that's it