# VBA Excel Chart on UserForm

Tags: excel, vba

I am looking for inspiration for a vba code that can display a diagram on a form.
The chart already has 3 charts on the active sheet.
I would like to have them displayed on a form.

How should the code be written in VBA for Excel?

I have asked chatGPT, it didn't help much...

Comment: Is the data changing (therefore also the charts changes all the time) or is it fix?

Comment: It is changing.

Comment: Is it changing while the form is displayed?

Comment: On the active sheet there is a calculation. I have made a diagram showing the S-curve for the mean value.
When the values in the calculation change, the diagram is updated accordingly.
I would like to allow the user to click a button to display a form with the current snapshot of the chart.
Is it possible?

Comment: You can't place a chart on a Userform. You could save the charts as images, place Image controls on the form and load the saved image. However, this will not look very nice. IMHO,  it is better to create a blank sheet and place the charts (or copies of them) on it.

Comment: Previously:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31598704/displaying-live-chart-data-in-excel-userform

Answer (score 0):

First, add an Image control to your UserForm.  This control will be used to display a picture of the chart.  Then place the following code in the UserForm code module.

Now, when the UserForm is shown, the code will first save the chart to a temporary GIF file in your temporary folder.  Then it will load it onto the Image control, and then it will delete the temporary file.

Change the name of the worksheet, chart, and Image control, accordingly.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    Dim tempFile As String
    tempFile = Environ("temp") & Application.PathSeparator & "temp.gif"
    
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").ChartObjects("Chart 1").Chart.Export filename:=tempFile, FilterName:="gif"
    
    Me.Image1.Picture = LoadPicture(tempFile)

    Kill tempFile
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Can the code be changed so that it only works on the active sheet?
I have several sheets with the same content, so everything has to happen on the active sheet so things don't get mixed up.

Comment: I changed

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Estimat").ChartObjects("S-kurve").Chart.Export Filename:=tempFile, FilterName:="gif"

with

ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("S-kurve").Chart.Export Filename:=tempFile, FilterName:="gif"

Comment: I see that you've amended the code as desired, so that's great.  Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I have come up with a temporary solution that seems to work just fine.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Vis_sKurve()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim shp As Shape

' Definerer arket og den aktive cellen
Set ws = ActiveSheet
Set rng = ActiveCell

' Loop gennem alle shapes på arket
For Each shp In ws.Shapes
    ' Sjekker om shape er en S-kurve shape
    If shp.Name = "S-kurve" Then
        ' Placér shape ved den aktive cellen
        shp.Top = rng.Top + rng.Height
        shp.Left = rng.Left
        shp.Visible = True
    End If
Next shp
' Rydder indhold i den aktive celle, så arket opdateres.
ActiveCell.ClearContents
End Sub

Sub Sluk_sKurve()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim shp As Shape

' Definerer arket
Set ws = ActiveSheet

' Loop gjennom alle shapes på arket
For Each shp In ws.Shapes
    ' Tjek at navn på shape er 'S-kurve'.
    If shp.Name = "S-kurve" Then
        ' Sluk for synlighed af shape.
        shp.Visible = False
    End If
Next shp

' Rydder indhold i den aktive celle, så arket opdateres.
ActiveCell.ClearContents

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Answer (score 0):

```vb
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim tempFile1 As String
    Dim tempFile2 As String
    Dim tempFile3 As String
      
    tempFile1 = Environ("temp") & Application.PathSeparator & "temp.gif"
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("SandsynlighedAnbefalet").Chart.Export Filename:=tempFile1, FilterName:="gif"
    Me.Image1.Picture = LoadPicture(tempFile1)
    Kill tempFile1


    tempFile2 = Environ("temp") & Application.PathSeparator & "temp.gif"
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("UsikkerhedAnbefalet").Chart.Export Filename:=tempFile2, FilterName:="gif"
    Me.Image2.Picture = LoadPicture(tempFile2)
    Kill tempFile2


    tempFile3 = Environ("temp") & Application.PathSeparator & "temp.gif"
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("RisikoAnbefalet").Chart.Export Filename:=tempFile3, FilterName:="gif"
    Me.Image3.Picture = LoadPicture(tempFile3)
    Kill tempFile3
End Sub
```

Comment: some customizations so that multiple charts are displayed on the same form.

Comment: a miner detail. I seemes like the charts must be moved to front, otherwise the kode will fail next time you open the file.